# Chrome Extension pop-up is blank

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I recently uploaded a chrome extension to the chrome store. It was approved, but when I installed it from the store, it only displays a small blank box like in the image below.

[image]

It probably has something to do with the way I am uploading the files. Below I have put how I uploaded them, and the manifest.json. Any ideas?

```
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Reminder-App",
  "version": "0.3.0",
  "description": "Reminder app for all your tasks",
  "icons": {
    "128": "tasks.png"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "./build/index.html",
    "default_title": "Reminder App",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "tasks.png",
      "24": "tasks.png",
      "32": "tasks.png"
    }
  },
  "permissions": ["storage"]
}
```

I compressed the build folder, the manifest.json, and the png from the image below into a zip file.

[image]

Comment: Any error inspecting that popup? Right click on the small blank box then "Inspect"

Comment: @Robbi yea in the console I got two errors: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND   main.7ecd1c96.js:1   -AND-    Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND   main.3352c99e.css:1

Comment: Assuming it works in your local unpacked extension, it's probably a bug in Chrome. Try removing `./` from default_popup, it's useless and is known to cause problems in the past.

Comment: @w0xx0m - Just tried it, still got the same issue. Any other ideas? I am all out! haha